# At which values of $x_0$ does $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} g(x)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

My answer is $(-\infty , -4) \cup (-4, \infty)$ but I am not sure if my answer is right.

[image]

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: oh my answer si right?

Comment: yeah your answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

The function is discontinuous at $x=-4$. All other points it is continuous.

Comment: No, is NOT continuous at x= 2.  The limit, as x goes 2, is 2 but f(2)= 1.

Comment: That could also have to do with the poor quality of the image. I didn't notice that feature until you pointed it out.